# Viewing Nested Records in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, console, records

I am trying to view nested records from the rails console.

I have subarticles nested into articles. In other words, subarticles belongs to article, and articles has many subarticles.

I have tried something like `Article.subarticle.all` from the console but this doesn't work.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Try `Article.includes(:subarticles)`

Comment: So you want to display all subarticles that have article attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to view all `subarticles` to one particular `Article`, you just need to assign it to a variable:

`a = Article.find(1)` - this will assign Article with `id = 1`

And then call:
`a.subarticles` - this will show all `subarticles` associated with your `Article`

Answer (score 3):

I think [`joins`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) is what you are looking for:

```
Article.joins(:subarticles)
```

will generate following SQL:

```
SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" INNER JOIN "subarticles" ON "subarticles"."article_id" = "article"."id"
```

Another option is to simply [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) all articles by its subarticles:

```
Article.all.map(&:subarticles)
```

It will return a relation with all subarticles where `article_id` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call `Article.subarticle.all`, you need to define an association in Article model.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :subarticles 
   ...
end
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html